# What does "Polite conversation is rarely either" mean?

Tags: quotes, meaning

What does the quote by Fran Lebowitz "Polite conversation is rarely either" mean?

Does it mean "If it's polite it's likely not a conversation, if it's a conversation it's likely not polite?"

Comment: I would say it means: A "polite conversation" is usually neither polite nor a conversation.

Comment: @GEdgar : That's a valid response to a valid (if its not a duplicate) question.  Why not post it so this question can have an answer?

Comment: @HotLicks Your comment explains the quote, rather than just repeating it in a slightly different way.  Too bad you didn't post it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Polite conversation is rarely either

I would say it means: A "polite conversation" is usually neither polite nor a conversation.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, if someone sees the need to characterize the discussion they have with someone else as "polite conversation" then they were probably being confrontational. You wouldn't casually say of a friendly chat, "I just had a polite conversation with my good friend Fred," but instead would use other words to characterize the discussion.